# Change color of institute in the footer of a Latex presentation

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I have a presentation that uses the theme `Dresden` with color theme `beaver`. Everything works fine, except for the name of the institute in the footer of the slides, which appears white on a very light grey background, making it basically impossible to read.

1. How can I change its color?
2. Why isn't the color changed automatically like, for example, the color of the author name in the footer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following line to your preamble, replacing `your_color` by a relevant color name

```
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=your_color}
```

The original definition is:

```
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
```

With `beaver` theme color defined as:

```
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=darkred!80!black,fg=gray!10!white}
```

That explains why the font color appears fast white....

Comment: Thanks! So I guess that the "author" fields have a different palette?

Comment: Yes, check the content of files like `beamercolorthemedefault.sty` and `beamercolorthemebeaver.sty`